# preg_match and preg_replace question

Tags: php, regex

I am creating dynamic XML and need to update the lastBuildDate in a file on my server.  I know how to do everything but change that.

I figured I could use preg_match to look for the expression and preg_replace to replace it.  My string will look like this:

```
$build_date = '<lastBuildDate>Fri 16 Sep 2011 2:30:15 -6:00 GMT<lastBuildDate>';
```

How do I use preg_match to find the date inside the tags and then how do I replace it?  I'm a noob when it comes to regular expressions, which is what I think I have to use.  I'm just not sure how to find a wildcard inside that string.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using an XML parser?

Comment: Don't parse XML or HTML with regex:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags  Instead, use an XML parser:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php

Comment: I didn't know that.  I didn't realize there was so much involved.  OK, I'll use an XML parser.  Thanks.

Comment: on the other hand it's helpful practice for a regex newbie to practice writing regex to parse tag's

Answer (score 1):

What I advise you to do is read the [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [PCRE syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) documentation, then use a tool such as [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) which will explain the regex you are writing with English words. It's a great tool to begin with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @downvoter: what if the data is not XML or HTML, but just a snippet in a file? The advice don't use regex to parse XML or HTML is great advice, but that doesn't mean it can be applied to any and all situations. Stop downvoting posts based on religious "omg don't use that it's evil" tirades. I didn't advocate specificaly using a regex in this case, I gave advice on how to learn to use a regex. Jeez....

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I think you're missing a '/' on your close tag. I'll assume there is supposed to be one.

Like what others have already commented, you should be using an XML parser.

But, to answer how to do this w/ preg_replace, you *could* do this:

```
$build_date = "<lastBuildDate>Fri 16 Sep 2011 2:30:15 -6:00 GMT</lastBuildDate>";

function replacer($matched) {
    return "<lastBuildDate>" . strrev($matched) . "</lastBuildDate>";
}

echo preg_replace("/<lastBuildDate>(.*?)<\/lastBuildDate>/me", "replacer('$1')", $build_date);
```

This will echo the xml tag, where (for the sake of example) the date string is simply reversed. Again, I'd advise against using an expression to do this.